# DataTable DataColumn ColumnName not displaying

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2013, datacolumn

I am new to VSTO and am encountering an issue I can't seem to figure out. I am trying to display a simple table in Excel 2013 and everything populates, except the column display names come out to be "Column1, Column2, Column3".

Here is my code:

```
        var worksheet = Globals.Sheet1;

        worksheet.Cells.Clear();

        var table = new DataTable("Users");

        // Set Columns
        var columns = new List<DataColumn>
        {
            new DataColumn("Staged") { ColumnName = "Staged", Caption = "Staged"},
            new DataColumn("FirstName") { ColumnName = "First Name", Caption = "First Name" },
            new DataColumn("LastName") { ColumnName = "Last Name", Caption = "Last Name"}
        };

        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(column);
        }


        var lastFilledRow = 1;

        // Populate data
        for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();
            row[table.Columns[0]] = "";
            row[table.Columns[1]] = "Joesph " + i;
            row[table.Columns[2]] = "Bellow " + i;

            table.Rows.Add(row);
            lastFilledRow++;
        }
        var lastCell = "C" + lastFilledRow;

        worksheet.Controls.Remove("userList");
        var list = worksheet.Controls.AddListObject(worksheet.Range["A1", lastCell], "userList");

        list.SetDataBinding(table);
```

Stepping through the code in debug mode, all the way through the code I cannot see any attributes set to "Column1", but they are set to the values provided. I know these are the default values for ColumnName.

My question is, Why are the ColumnNames printing out in excel as Column1, Column2, Column3 when I'm explictly setting the values for ColumnName?

Comment: Does this link and especially the example solves your problem?
Looks like you need to use the third ctor
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x81bad6y.aspx

Comment: @PetLahev Nope. Still doesn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to name the columns explicitly.  After `var list = ...` add the following:

```
list.ListColumns[1].Name = "Staged";
list.ListColumns[2].Name = "First Name";
list.ListColumns[3].Name = "Last Name";
```