# Set dynamic column names when using Adapter.Fill , filling a DataTable with SQL Server conn

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, sqldataadapter

I'm filling a DataTable with SQL Server query results like so:

```
System.Data.DataTable dataTableSQL = new System.Data.DataTable();

// write the sqlCode to dataTableSQL via adapter
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=myServerName;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security = SSPI"))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(SQLCode, conn);

    conn.Open();
    adapter.Fill(dataTableSQL);
    conn.Close();
}
```

This method seams to be omitting the column names from the dataTable. When I run the below code, I just get the first row of the query results:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dataTableSQL.Columns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dataTableSQL.Rows[0][column.ColumnName].ToString());
}
```

Here is a helpful reference, but unfortunately my tables are 30 + columns long, and my column names are dynamic, so it does me no good. [DataTable DataColumn ColumnName not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773323/datatable-datacolumn-columnname-not-displaying)

Is there an easy way to add dynamic column names to a dataTable so I can use them in reporting?

Comment: The column names are not in row zero.  They are in an enumeration dataTableSQL.Columns property.  Should be : Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);

Comment: @jdweng perfect man thank you